# Why is UISearchController behaving differently than UIViewController, its superclass?

Tags: ios, inheritance, uiviewcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I have some code here:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let color = addButton.backgroundColor
    theSearchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1
    theSearchBar.layer.borderColor = color?.cgColor
}
```

That gets rid of the border on my `UISearchBar`. This code was working fine for me.
Then I changed my view controller from a subclass of `UIViewController` to a subclass of `UISearchController`. Now according to my understanding, my code should still work because `UISearchController` inherits from `UIViewController` and therefore should have all the same functionality. But now I get an error saying that `addButton.backgroundColor` is nil. why?

Comment: You may need to re associate the reference to the button.  CTRL drag from the interface builder to the class code and make sure it is still associated correctly.  Xcode does weird things some times when you change subclasses.

Comment: Resetting outlets didn't fix it.

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: It throws the good old "found nil while unwrapping optional value" when I try to access the button's background color on line 3. The color should be there by the time viewDidLoad is called.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup I can't access any properties of any of my IBOutlets in viewDidLoad

Comment: Do they work in viewDidAppear?

Comment: No, they don't work in viewDidAppear either

Comment: Post your whole view controller class please.